# Testing react components componentDidMount, how do I render into a new document after each test?

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

Tests run, but they are rendering into the same document. On componentDidMount Style component appends CSS text to a style element in head with the class `.reactive-style` (know this is unorthodox and not idiosyncratic React). If `.reactive-style` does not already exist then the style element is created and added to head. Testing wise -- for simplicities sake -- I need to render into a new document for each test case.

Tests look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { findDOMNode, render } from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

const removeNewlines = (string) => (string.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ''))

import Style from '../src/index.js';

describe('Style', () => {

  it('scopes only one root selector if a selector is union root selector', () => {
    const myTestUtils = Object.assign({}, TestUtils);
    const wrapper = myTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <div>
        <Style>
          {`
            #box.rootClass { color: red; }
          `}

          <div id="box" className="rootClass" />
        </Style>
      </div>
    );

    const rootNode = findDOMNode(wrapper).children[0];
    const styleNode = document.head.querySelector('.reactive-style');

    expect(rootNode.className).toEqual('rootClass _scoped-1830358384');
    expect( removeNewlines(styleNode.textContent) )
      .toEqual(` #box._scoped-1356475730.rootClass , ._scoped-1356475730  #box.rootClass { color: red; }`);
  });

  it('preserves quotes for the CSS property "content"', () => {
    const myTestUtils = Object.assign({}, TestUtils);
    const wrapper = myTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <div>
          <Style>
            {`
                .Slide:before { content: " test "; }
                .Slide:after { content: " "; }

                .Foo:after {
                  position: absolute;
                  content: "";
                  width: 100%;
                  height: 100%;
                  backgroud-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .7);
                  top: 0;
                  left: 0;
                  z-index: 1;
                }
              `}

            <div className="Slide" />
          </Style>
        </div>
    );

    const rootNode = findDOMNode(wrapper).children[0];
    const styleNode = document.head.querySelector('.reactive-style');

    expect(rootNode.className).toEqual('Slide _scoped-864836516');
    expect( removeNewlines(styleNode.textContent) )
      .toEqual(` .Slide._scoped-864836516:before , ._scoped-864836516  .Slide:before { content: ' test '; } .Slide._scoped-864836516:after , ._scoped-864836516  .Slide:after { content: ' '; }._scoped-864836516  .Foo:after { position: absolute; content: ''; width: 100%; height: 100%; backgroud-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .7); top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1; }`);
  });
});
```

Current output showing the innerHTML of the target style element in head growing with each test (undesired, want new document for each test case):

```
 FAIL  __tests__/Style.js (0.613s)
● Style › it scopes only one root selector if a selector is union root selector
  - Expected ' #box._scoped-1830358384.rootClass , ._scoped-1830358384  #box.rootClass { color: red; }' to equal ' #box._scoped-1356475730.rootClass , ._scoped-1356475730  #box.rootClass { color: red; }'.
        at jasmine.buildExpectationResult (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/index.js:80:44)
        at Object.eval (__tests__/Style.js:315:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine-pit.js:35:32)
        at jasmine2 (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/index.js:253:7)
        at Test.run (node_modules/jest-cli/src/Test.js:44:12)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
● Style › it preserves quotes for the CSS property "content"
  - Expected ' #box._scoped-1830358384.rootClass , ._scoped-1830358384  #box.rootClass { color: red; }' to equal ' .Slide._scoped-864836516:before , ._scoped-864836516  .Slide:before { content: ' test '; } .Slide._scoped-864836516:after , ._scoped-864836516  .Slide:after { content: ' '; }._scoped-864836516  .Foo:after { position: absolute; content: ''; width: 100%; height: 100%; backgroud-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .7); top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1; }'.
        at jasmine.buildExpectationResult (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/index.js:80:44)
        at Object.eval (__tests__/Style.js:349:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine-pit.js:35:32)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/jasmine-pit.js:40:11)
        at jasmine2 (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/index.js:253:7)
        at Test.run (node_modules/jest-cli/src/Test.js:44:12)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
2 tests failed, 0 tests passed (2 total in 1 test suite, run time 1.323s)
```

See how the second test includes results from the first? Goal is to avoid that by rendering to a new document.

Have tried several things, like blanking out the innerHTML of the `.reactive-style` element via `document.head.querySelector('.reactive-style').innerHTML = '';` but when `expect()` runs the `styleNode.textContent` shows as empty so that does not work (presumably because `expect()` is running async and the `innerHTML` is cleared synchronously). Cheers and thanks for any assistance.